# monkeyrunner touch event recognized as longpress

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

created a monkeyrunner script to play with an app im working with.  Problem is where-ever a long tap is enabled device.touch(Y,X,"DOWN_AND_UP") is recognized as a longtap.  I've noticed in the logs that whenever a method is called it's run twice.

10-28 09:08:04.983: DEBUG/MonkeyStub(2608): translateCommand: touch down 300 800
10-28 09:08:04.983: DEBUG/MonkeyStub(2608): translateCommand: touch down 300 800

any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I didn't put a MonkeyRunner.sleep(0.5) in between each of my calls they are usually called too fast in relation to each other. Thus, the system doesn't get a moment to realize that the 'touch' is actually gone. Kind of a kludge but that's what I believe is going on.